# How do I calculate the strength gain for years of work?

Tags: training, runequest

I am trying to understand what it means by "+1 strength per 3 years of work experience or fraction" in the RuneQuest 3 Player's book.

Does that mean if somebody worked for 4 years they would receive +2 strength?

I've also seen it mention something along the lines of "+1 strength per 3 years of work experience or fraction thereof". Is this the same as above?

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the (adventuring) party, but my reading would be:

- 1-3 years: +1 STR *(starting at 1 full year, so as not to get an automatic bump at one day!)*
- 4-6 years: +2 STR
- 7-9 years: +3 STR
- ...and so on, based on **completed** years of work experience.

However, as a GM I'd set an upper bound of species normal (rollable) characteristic maximum: thus 18 for humans. If you want better than that, you're going to have to train specifically for strength, rather than have it happen as a consequence of your trade. Even then, you'll be bound by the species maximum: for humans, 21.

That all said, I'd strongly recommend moving over to RuneQuest: Glorantha (RQG) rules. This isn't the place for a long explanation of why, but you won't regret it.

In the RQG rules, there's a different aging mechanic, which doesn't include the STR bonus you mention. That doesn't sadden me. I'd find it hard to justify, for example, a Chalanna Arroy Healer or a moccasin maker gaining +2 STR after four years in the business. It's not comparable to how a blacksmith or a combat trainer, to pick two, would strengthen up. It also prevents players from metagaming a year in trade to gain a free STR point.